# Как упростить поиск индекса элемента в массиве?

Tags: java, массивы

Можно ли упростить такой код?

```java
logicString.charAt(Arrays.stream(logicTTArray).toList().indexOf(currentType));
```

Comment: Добавьте типы `logicTTArray`  и `currentType`. И ещё укажите, хотите сделать код короче или ускорить его работу

Answer (score 4):

Преобразование в `stream` с последующей конвертацией в список излишне, массив конвертируется в список при помощи классического метода [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) или [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/List.html#of-E...-), начиная с Java 9:

```java
logicString.charAt(Arrays.asList(logicTTArray).indexOf(currentType));
```

Если массив `logicTTArray` отсортирован, можно использовать более быстрый бинарный поиск [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-):

```java
logicString.charAt(Arrays.binarySearch(logicTTArray, currentType));
```

---

Однако, поскольку суть задачи состоит в том, что требуется найти некий символ в строке `logicString`, расположенный по *индексу* элемента `currentType` в массиве `logicTTArray`, можно предложить решение на основе некоторого перечисления, хранящего символы для каждого "ключа" `currentType` (вместо строки `logicString`).

Тогда поиск будет реализован за постоянное время:

```java
enum MyType {
    A('a'), B('b'),
    // ...
    Y('y'), Z('z');

    private char symbol;

    private MyType(char c) { this.symbol = c;}

    public char getSymbol() { return this.symbol;}
}
```

Здесь эквивалентом массива `logicTTArray` может быть массив значений перечисления `MyType.values()`, и соответственно `currentType` будет сразу содержать нужный символ:

```java
MyType currentType = MyType.Z;
char tt = currentType.getSymbol();
```